# range() for calculating balance with interval

Tags: python, pandas

My output is as follows:

```
        ISIN    DatesforAccrual          Days   Accrual@Coupon  Balance       AccrualYield
    0   Test1   October 22nd, 2019       0      0.00            4,875,358.20    nan
    1   Test1   February 8th, 2020       106    83,638.42       4,819,281.81    27,562.03
    2   Test1   August 8th, 2020         180    142,027.50      4,723,519.41    46,265.11
    3   Test1   February 8th, 2021       180    142,027.50      4,626,837.70    45,345.79
    4   Test1   June 19th, 2021          131    103,364.46      4,555,799.41    32,326.17
    5   Test2   July 31st, 2020          0      0.00            4,555,799.41    0.00
    6   Test2   September 21st, 2020    51      12,661.46       4,555,529.73    12,391.77
    7   Test2   March 21st, 2021        180     44,687.50       4,554,575.32    43,733.09
    8   Test2   June 19th, 2021          88     21,847.22       4,554,104.23    21,376.14
    9   Test3   January 1st, 2021         0      0.00           4,554,104.23    0.00
    10  Test3   April 3rd, 2021           92     8,025.98       4,568,423.73    22,345.47
    11  Test3   June 19th, 2021           76     6,630.16       4,580,310.92    18,517.34
```

Code as per below

```
       import QuantLib as ql
        import pandas as pd
       import numpy as np
       import datetime

       data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Avishen\Desktop\Python\BONDDATA.xlsx')
       data['issuedate'] = data['issuedate'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
       data['maturitydate'] = data['maturitydate'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

       t_list = []
       t1_list = []
       t2_list = []
       t3_list = []
       t4_list = []

       for _, row in data.iterrows():
           today = ql.Date.todaysDate()
           issueDate = ql.Date(row['issuedate'], '%d-%m-%Y')
           maturityDate = ql.Date(row['maturitydate'], '%d-%m-%Y')
           tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
           day_count = ql.Thirty360
           coupon=(row['coupon'])
           Tradeyield = (row['Tradeyield'])
           Bond_Price = (row['Bond_Price'])
           face_value=100
           Nominal_Amount=(row['Nominal_Amount'])
           calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
           businessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
           dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
           monthEnd = False
           schedule = ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor,        calendar, ql.Unadjusted,ql.Unadjusted, dateGeneration, monthEnd)
           DatesinCoupon  =  list(schedule)
           Balance = 100

           DatesinCouponfiltered = list(filter(lambda score: score        <today, DatesinCoupon))
           DatesforAccrual = DatesinCouponfiltered + [today]

           NoofDaysinAccrual=[0]+[int(ql.Thirty360().yearFraction(start, end)*360) for start, end in zip(DatesforAccrual[:-1],        DatesforAccrual[1:])]

       Calculate Accrued interest in each coupon period 

           if day_count == ql.Thirty360:
               DC = (360)
           elif day_count == ql.Thirty365:
               DC = (365)
           else:
               DC = (366)
       
           AccruedCoupon = [(i * (coupon))/(DC) *face_value *Nominal_Amount/100 for i in NoofDaysinAccrual]

           t_list.append(row['ISIN'])
           t1_list.append(DatesforAccrual)
           t2_list.append(NoofDaysinAccrual)
           t3_list.append(AccruedCoupon)
           t4_list.append(Nominal_Amount*Bond_Price/100)
           new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN':t_list,        'DatesforAccrual':t1_list,'Days':t2_list,'Accrual@Coupon':t3_list})
           s = new_df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
           s.loc[s.drop_duplicates('ISIN').index, "Balance"] = (t4_list)

           for i in range(1, len(s),1):
               s.loc[i, 'AccrualYield'] = s.loc[i-1,'Balance']*s.loc[i,'Days']* Tradeyield / DC
               s.loc[i , 'Balance'] = s.loc[i-1,'Balance']-s.loc[i,'Accrual@Coupon']+ s.loc[i,'AccrualYield']
```

Values from the excel as per below

```
ISIN    issuedate   maturitydate    coupon  Tradeyield  Bond_Price  MarketPrice Nominal_Amount
Test1   22-Oct-19   08-Aug-23   6.53%   2.37%       112.0772    110.787     4,350,000 
Test2   31-Jul-20   21-Mar-25   3.25%   3.30%       111.235     109.253     2,750,000 
Test3   01-Jan-21   03-Apr-24   2.51%   1.92%       109.4521    113.4561     1,251,235
```

I want the balance to stop calculating at row 4, and start again at row 6, then stop again at row 8 and start again at row 10, then stop at row 11. This will continue again based on the `ISIN` in the df. How can I achieve this?

Expexted Output:

```
    ISIN    DatesforAccrual     Days    Accrual@Coupon  AccrualYield    Balance
0   Test1   October 22nd, 2019          0   0       4,875,358.20
1   Test1   February 8th, 2020  106 83,638.42   34,021.87   4,825,741.65
2   Test1   August 8th, 2020    180 142,027.50  57,185.04   4,740,899.19
3   Test1   February 8th, 2021  180 142,027.50  56,179.66   4,655,051.35
4   Test1   June 19th, 2021     131 103,364.46  40,145.94   4,591,832.83
5   Test2   July 31st, 2020         0   0           3,058,962.50
6   Test2   September 21st, 2020    51  12,661.46   14,300.65   3,060,601.69
7   Test2   March 21st, 2021    180 44,687.50   50,499.93   3,066,414.12
8   Test2   June 19th, 2021     88  21,847.22   24,735.74   3,069,302.64
9   Test3   January 1st, 2021       0   0           1,369,502.98
10  Test3   April 3rd, 2021     92  8,025.98    11,549.48   1,373,026.48
11  Test3   June 19th, 2021     76  6,630.16    9,565.42    1,375,961.74
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible data snippet of your **input** dataframe. The thing you show at the top is your current (sligtly wrong) output, not your input, right? We need to see your input dataframe.

Comment: Ok but now your minimal example is still 45 lines long, can you please strip it down to something more tractable? Eliminate all unnecessary variables, columns, temporaries please. This is what we mean by [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
s.groupby('ISIN')
```

Then the idea is to chain that into `.agg()`, `.apply()` or so on.

Also, to iterate over the rows of a dataframe you generally never need to write a for-loop and access each column with `s.loc[i, colname]`. Use `.apply()` or `.sum()` or other operations. And when you need to access the previous row (in that ISIN group), use `.shift(-1)`

Something like:

```
s['AccrualYield'] = s.['Balance'].shift(-1) * s['NoofDaysinAccrual'] * Tradeyield / DC
```

If you can post a reproducible data snippet then I'll try to show the compleet expression for `s['Balance']`

Comment: I have added the full code and the expected output in the question. Hope it can help. Thank you

Comment: Any help friends